# Resources on how to explain well

Tags: reference-request, education

I stumbled upon this [blog post](https://jvns.ca/blog/confusing-explanations/) by Julia Evans. She gives some anti-patterns that make explanations confusing.

I am wondering if there is more resources on this topic.
I am looking for general tips (like the ones presented by Julia) and math-specific tips.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps better suited to https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/